# Need help creating a javascript or a bootstrap like popup modal for a form submission in Telesope meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor, popup, window

Hi I'm using meteor site http://www.telesc.pe and need help making the submit form link open in a pop window or javascript overlay vs a new page with a close button.

Any suggestions?

## newtometeor

Thanks!

Comment: can you try something? and paste what you tried here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) via the [bootstrap-3 package](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/bootstrap-3).

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Then refer to the Boostrap documentation. Should be pretty easy.